# Is it safe to use performance.now() to measure page load time in GWT?

Tags: gwt, page-load-time

I need to measure the time required for my GWT application to load.

I can't use GWT Lightweight Metrics because of external framework usage (I can't modify bootstrap html page).

Navigation Timing doesn't work for GWT because initialization of GWT widgets doesn't depend on window.load.

So, is it safe to use performance.now() method to get the time from PerformanceTiming.navigationStart event?

[Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#dom-performance-now) says that:

> The now() method must return a DOMHighResTimeStamp representing the time in milliseconds from the time origin to the occurrence of the call to the Performance.now method.

I can't understand [time origin definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#time-origin). Does it always return the time from the moment when the user requests a page with my application?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found answer to my original question. It seems like performance.now() isn't suitable for measuring page loading time.

I have used explicit approach described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API).

The code is something like this.

```
public static long getTimeFromPageLoadStart() {
  long navigationStart = (long) getNavigationStart();
  return new Date().getTime() - navigationStart;
}

private static native double getNavigationStart()/*-{
  return performance.timing.navigationStart;
}-*/;
```